# Passing data from Activity to ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I'm very newbie using MvvmCross and I have an issue. I want to implement taking a photo in an Activity, the native way, but I don't know how I can pass data to the ViewModel.

There is a way to do that?

Comment: Do you reference your ViewModel in your Activity class ? Don't you have some properties on your ViewModel that you can get/set from your Activity ?

Comment: Mvvmcross use convention to make reference between ViewModel and Activity. I not found how can put data into ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing data to a ViewModel is fairly easy. If you are in the Activity and given that it inherits from MvxActivity or the likes you will have the `ViewModel` property you can access directly from it.

There are also generic versions of these activities, so you don't have to type cast the `ViewModel` property yourself.

So if you have:

```
public class MyActivity : MvxActivity<PictureViewModel>
{

}
```

Then you can access `ViewModel`:

```
ViewModel.SomeViewModelProperty = myData;
```

This `myData` object could be a byte array with the picture data.

MvvmCross does have a Picture taking plugin already, which uses the built in Android camera to take pictures with. If you add

```
MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser
```

To both your Android and Core project, then you can use the `IMvxPictureChooserTask` directly in the `ViewModel` without involving anything else:

```
public class PictureViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private IMvxPictureChooserTask _pictureTask;
    public PictureViewModel(IMvxPictureChooserTask pictureTask)
    {
        _pictureTask = pictureTask;
    }

    private byte[] _pictureBytes;

    // in some command:
    private void DoTakePicture()
    {
        _pictureTask.TakePicture(500, 500, stream => {
            _pictureBytes = ReadStream(stream);
        }, () => {});
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks